# will_paginate and named_routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have some problems using `will_paginate` and named routes.

Here is some code (my site is in Spanish language):

routes.rb

```
map.animals '/animales/:scope/:id', :controller => :categories, :action => :show
```

with these routes I generate URLs like:

```
www.domain.com/animales/mamiferos/perros
```

but, when pages links are generated I get links like:

```
www.domain.com/animals/perros?page=2&scope=mamiferos
```

Why are they like that?

---

*NOTE: I am also using* `friendly_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that there is no matching route before the animals route in the routes.rb file. E.g. the default route *map.connect ":controller/:action/:id"* and the resource definition *map.resources :animals* should come after the named animals route.

Comment: I don't think that is my case, I have

map.animals '/animales/:scope/:id', :controller => :categories, :action => :show

... many lines after ...

map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'

Comment: do you have a _map.resources :animals_ somewhere before?

Comment: yes, I have a map.resources :animals before ;( I removed it and now it's works! thk!
(May be you can edit your answer to give a more complete detail)